# Can I change sensitivity of line input level? (as opposed to setting the volume)

Tags: macos, audio, imac

I'm connecting a standard stereo tape output to an iMac line input socket. Setting input level in System Preferences > Sound > Input > Line In requires the slider to be barely "off the stop" before the blue level meter hits hard right.  Can I lower the line input sensitivity somehow?  There's no output level control on the tape output.

I'm running Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [LineIn](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/) by Rogue Amoeba?

Comment: No, but thank you for the link ... I will give it a try.

Comment: It doesn't do what I would like - not even a volume control.  So temporarily I'm padding the line down with a few 10k resistors (real old school stuff!).